# transparency.js nested plain values

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, template-engine, transparency.js

I was wondering why the following doesn't work:

Coffeescript:

```
post =
  title:    'Hello World',
  post:     'Hi there it is me',
  comments: [
    name: 'John',
    text: 'That rules'
  ,
    name: 'Arnold',
    text: 'Great post!',
    tags: ['a', 'b', 'c']
  ]

directives =
  tags:
    tag: 
      text: (target) -> this.value


$('.container').render post, directives
```

Template:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="title"></h1>
  <p class="post"></p>
  <div class="comments">
    <div class="comment">
      <span class="name"></span>
      <span class="text"></span>
      <div class="tags">
        <span class='tag'></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It doesn't render the nested plain tags, nor does it ever execute the directive function for them

Any ideas?

Comment: `<span class='tag'>` is never closed.

Comment: @Alex: That was a typo and I corrected the question. I just checked on http://leonidas.github.com/transparency/ and the tags still don't show up in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct set of directives:

```
directives =
  comments:
    tags:
      tag:
        text: (target) -> this.value
```

Directives don't cascade by skipping unmentioned top layers the way normal values do, so you had to include the `comments` layer.